# How do I resolve error 443 using api.bls in R

Tags: r, tls1.2

I have been running api.bls in R successfully. However, BLS (Bureau of Labor Statistics) increased its security level and now I am getting this error message: 
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :
  Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.bls.gov:443

BLS recommended that I turn-off settings TLS 1.0 and use TLS 1.2.

This doesn't help, I am still getting the same message.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Technically this is not a question that fits the premise of the close vote reason starting with: "Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') ..." since thi has no code, but that seems the most fitting reason anyway.

Comment: OK- here is the code in R: library(blsAPI)

payload <- list("seriesid"="CES0000000001", "startyear"="2010","endyear"="2018")
emp00 <- blsAPI(payload,1,TRUE)

Comment: I get no error when I run that code. Make sure you have the most recent version. Try again. Perhaps add `library(rjson)` since that was present in help page code.

Comment: Code needs to go in the question (you can edit your post), not comments where it's very difficult to read